# Error Switch scenes in Scene Builder (JavaFx)

Tags: java, javafx, scenebuilder

I'm trying to do a graphic interface for an university activity using Scene builder. I need to switch the window when pressed the button so I created a function that changes the window when the button is pressed and included this action on the button by SceneBuilder and it worked, but when I tried to do the same thing for a button on the new window I got this error:

```html
Executing C:\Users\Luke\Desktop\tp1\dist\run887860135\tp1.jar using platform C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_221\jre/bin/java
out 04, 2019 7:05:11 PM javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ValueElement processValue
WARNING: Loading FXML document with JavaFX API of version 11.0.1 by JavaFX runtime of version 8.0.221
out 04, 2019 7:05:11 PM javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ValueElement processValue
WARNING: Loading FXML document with JavaFX API of version 11.0.1 by JavaFX runtime of version 8.0.221
Exception in Application start method
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
 at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
 at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplicationWithArgs(LauncherImpl.java:389)
 at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication(LauncherImpl.java:328)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
 at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
 at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper$FXHelper.main(LauncherHelper.java:767)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception in Application start method
 at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1(LauncherImpl.java:917)
 at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication$1(LauncherImpl.java:182)
 at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: javafx.fxml.LoadException: Error resolving onAction='#BTADDCLIENTEAction', either the event handler is not in the Namespace or there is an error in the script.
file:/C:/Users/Luke/Desktop/tp1/dist/run887860135/tp1.jar!/tp1/Cliente.fxml:8

 at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.constructLoadException(FXMLLoader.java:2597)
 at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.access$100(FXMLLoader.java:103)
 at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$Element.processEventHandlerAttributes(FXMLLoader.java:610)
 at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ValueElement.processEndElement(FXMLLoader.java:770)
 at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.processEndElement(FXMLLoader.java:2823)
 at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2532)
 at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2441)
 at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3214)
 at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3175)
 at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3148)
 at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3124)
 at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3104)
 at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(FXMLLoader.java:3097)
 at tp1.Tp1.start(Tp1.java:42)
 at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$8(LauncherImpl.java:863)
 at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$7(PlatformImpl.java:326)
 at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$null$5(PlatformImpl.java:295)
 at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
 at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$6(PlatformImpl.java:294)
 at com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:95)
 at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
 at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$null$3(WinApplication.java:177)
 ... 1 more
Exception running application tp1.Tp1
Java Result: 1
```

than I tried to remove the Action from this button and the code compiled so the error probably is on the action but I have no idea how to solve, could anyone help me?

The function to switch the window:

```html
  private void BTADDCLIENTEAction(ActionEvent event) throws IOException {
        Parent main_parent = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("addCliente.fxml"));
        Scene ClienteScene = new Scene(main_parent);
        Stage mainStage =  (Stage) ((Node) event.getSource()).getScene().getWindow();
        mainStage.setScene(ClienteScene);
        mainStage.show();
    }
```

Comment: Are you sure you didn't accidentally import `java.awt.event.ActionEvent` instead of `javafx.event.ActionEvent`? If you aren't going to make use of the `ActionEvent` object, you can remove the parameter, as it's optional.

Comment: @VinceEmigh yeah, I'm importing `javafx.event.ActionEvent` , still don't knowing where is the error =(

Comment: Is your method annotated with `@FXML`? `FXMLLoader` only considers methods annotated with this annotation or `public` methods...

Comment: I found the error, it was a stupid thing, sorry for being newbie guys. I was putting the functions of the buttonaction on the controller of the window to where they were supossed to switch, but I should put on the controller of the window where the buttons were. Anyway, thanks for the help =)